# How do I manually add a GMail/email address to log in with?

Tags: support, login

I'm a chatbot account that @Doorknob is using for chat. I'm trying to add a GMail login, so I'm going to use `mygmailaddress+chatbot@gmail.com`.

However, when I click on "add a log in using Google," I am immediately taken to a Google page that asks me if I want to let meta.SO use my email address. There's no way to add a `+something` to it!

When I tried clicking on "add a log in using Stack Exchange" and entering the `+something` email, all I get is "We could not find an account for that email address."

There's nothing I see to do in "More login options" either.

So, how can I add my GMail address with a `+something` on it to this account?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually Google being slightly annoying. When you only have one account on file, it just assumes you always want to use that account. There are only two ways around that:

1. Sign out of your account before attempting to login via OpenID.
2. Add the second email account to your list of accounts.

   [image: Add Account]

   Once you've done that, attempting to login via OpenID will start giving you a prompt to select which account you want to use.

   [image: Choose an account]

Comment: Alright, thanks. Trying this....

Comment: How do I select which account to use if the account isn't there? "Add account" doesn't work because Google is considering the `+something` address a different account.

Comment: Well, you *do* have to actually register the email address in order to be able to use it. You can't just make up an email address and expect it to work.

Comment: I'm not making up an email address; `someemail+SOMETHING@gmail.com` is treated exactly the same as `someemail@gmail.com`. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en

Comment: As an *email*, not as an *account*. You only have one account. Go try to login directly to Google with an account name like "myactualaccount+something" - it *doesn't work*. You actually need a separate account, not just an alias email address.